# ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a simple addon in Firefox - 24, on Linux.
I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
```

when I do: var encoder = new TextEncoder();
the function I'm using is:

```
function write_text(filename, text) {
    var encoder = new TextEncoder();
    var data = encoder.encode(text);
    Task.spawn(function() {
       let pfh =  OS.File.open("/tmp/foo", {append: true});
       yield pfh.write(text);
       yield pfh.flush();
       yield pfh.close(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: I upgraded my nodejs version to latest and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, you're using the SDK, I gather when re-reading the actual error of your other question.

- You need to import `TextEncoder` explicitly from some other module, as SDK modules lack the class.
- You need to `yield` OS.File.open.
- `append:` is only supported in Firefox 27+
- `.flush()` is only supported in Firefox 27+ (and a bad idea anyway). Use `.writeAtomic` if you need that.
- You `write: true` to write to a file.

Here is a full, working example I tested in Firefox 25 (`main.js`)

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
// It is important to load TextEncoder like this using Cu.import()
// You cannot load it by just |Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm");|
const {TextEncoder, OS} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {});
const {Task} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm", {});

function write_text(filename, text) {
    var encoder = new TextEncoder();
    var data = encoder.encode(text);
    filename = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.tmpDir, filename);
    Task.spawn(function() {
       let file = yield OS.File.open(filename, {write: true});
       yield file.write(data);
       yield file.close(); 
       console.log("written to", filename);
    }).then(null, function(e) console.error(e));
}

write_text("foo", "some text");
```

Answer (score 61):

if you are having this error while running node server

locate this file `node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/encoding.js` or `.../lib/encoding.js`

add this line at top `const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("util");`

Comment: This worked but the path has changed to `node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js`

Comment: After add the line  const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("util"),. run npm  install.

Answer (score 30):

In nodejs you can solve with util:

```
var util= require('util');
var encoder = new util.TextEncoder('utf-8');
```

Comment: Where to add this?

Answer (score 18):

If you experienced this because of using Mongodb via `npm install mongodb` then the simplest way is just to upgrade your Node Version. Needs to be higher than version 12; I used version 16 and it clearly fixed my problem

Comment: The project I was trying to install the dependancies on used a higher version of NodeJS without specifying the NodeJS version used. I needed to add a nvm config file and specify the latest version of NodeJS. My local version of NodeJS was using an older version of NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks, updating Nodejs solved the problem. I used Ubuntu 20, where node v10 is installed by default.

Comment: I am using node 14 and still has this

Comment: Kindly try version 16

Comment: What does MongoDB have to do with this...?

Answer (score 14):

1. **This issue occurs in node 10 or lower version only.** To resolve this issue `upgrade node version to 12 or higher` and then `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`
2. **Or If you don't want to upgrade node version, then,**

   Locate this file

   ```
   node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/encoding.js // If dist folder

   node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js // If lib folder
   ```

   And add this line in encoding.js file

   ```
   const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("./utils"); // if utils file

   const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("./util"); // if util file
   ```

Comment: I am using typescript, where to add this?

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting this error so I solved it in this way,
in nodejs project go to the node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/encoding.js file in that add this line =>

```
const {TextDecoder, TextEncoder} = require("util");
```

And your problem is solved

Comment: This would be a problem if you ever need to reinstall npm packages or update etc. How will you track this change?

Comment: What? manually change the file in dist folder? How is this going to work in a clean deployment where everything is rebuilt?

Answer (score 3):

A text encoder for `Node.js` can be found in the `util` [module](https://nodejs.org/dist./v8.4.0/docs/api/util.html#util_class_util_textencoder). You can access it like so:

```
const util = require('util');
const TextEncoder = new util.TextEncoder();
```

One of the roles of the `TextEncoder` is to convert a string of text into an array of bytes. You can achieve this like so:

```
const data = TextEncoder.encode(
   JSON.stringify({ c: "Green" })
);
// Uint8Array [ 123, 34, 99, 34, 58, 34, 71, 114, 101, 101, 110, 34, 125 ]
```

The array returned is called a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array). It consists of integers in the range 0 to 255.

Note that `TextEncoder` only supports `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 2):

For me upgrade Node.js version resolved this issue

Answer (score 2):

Open your encoding.js folder in node_modules>whatwg-url>dist

And in place of:

```
"use strict";
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });
```

Write this code:

```
"use strict";
var util= require('util');
const utf8Encoder = new util.TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new util.TextDecoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });
```

all you where missing is this small part by including utils.

Answer (score 1):

The `TextEncoder` can be found in the `sdk/io/buffer` module:

```
let { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('sdk/io/buffer')
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an error in node_modules/whatwg_url/dist/encoding.js folder then uninstall MongoDB by

```
npm uninstall mongodb
```

and reinstall it

```
npm install --save mongodb
```

Comment: Try to install mongoose by npm install mongoose

Comment: Wrt to mongoose: since version v6.x it requires NodeJS >= v12.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem in my project but I fixed this issue by upgrading my **node version** from **10** to **12**. May be this issue now a days can occurred due to lower version of node we are using in our project.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a node version error because I solved it by updating from 10 to 16 and after that, I installed dependencies and open a new terminal.

1. Update node to 14 or higher, I used Node Version Manager (NVM)
2. Delete node_modules directory, on linux:

   rm -rf node_modules
3. Install dependencies with npm install
4. Close and open a new terminal
5. Run app with node or nodemon

Done!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when running automated tests with [jest](https://jestjs.io/) and rendering a component that included `import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react"`.

The solution is to mock out that function as follows:

```js
jest.mock('ag-grid-react', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  AgGridReact: jest.fn((x) => <div>{x.children}</div>),
  AgGridColumn: jest.fn(() => <div />),
}));
```

Comment: How can I use this to render a component in another folder

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error, because of having to install old nodejs. This problem can be solved by installing the latest nodejs.
To update nodejs to nodejs to 14.x

sudo apt update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install -y nodejs
node -v

Answer (score 0):

This might help others.

I was getting the same error and I almost tried all the above solutions, but nothing works for me. Finally, I update the npm version and everything is fine.

When I installed the **Next App** the npm version was **6.14.4**.

I update the version and all errors are fixed you don't need to change anything in the core files just update the version in my case recommended ***8.11.0***.

```
npm -v // Check the version

npm install -g npm@latest // Get the latest version
```

**OR**

```
npm install -g npm@8.11.0 // Get the Spacific version
```

Complete guid [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)

Answer (score 0):

It's a node version problem.
[Described by @yhojann-cl here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10713#issuecomment-921373677)

I have the same problem:
In `/usr/bin/node` I have 10.x, but 16.x is installed by `nvm`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had multiple node versions installed, and current project required a more recent node version. To fix the problem I did the following steps.

To check the current version of node running, in the terminal use the command

```
node --version
```

Output in the Terminal :

[image]

The following command will list the different node versions already installed in your system.

```
nvm ls
```

Output in the Terminal :

[image]

To switch to more recent version of the node ie, v16.17.0, use the following command in the terminal

```
nvm use v16.17.0
```

Output in the Terminal :

[image]

Now confirm the current version of the node by

```
node --version
```

Output in Terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getitng the same error after adding the mongodb, i resolve it by upgrading to node version

```
nvm use 16.16.0
```

Answer (score -1):

in case you get this error while running tests:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74864115

Setting the testEnvironment to node in my `jest.config` file fixed it
(https://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html)

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

Answer (score -2):

TextEncoder is native function in javascript, check the version that suit the ability.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder#browser_compatibility

Chrome version >=38, Edge version >=79, Firefox version >=18, Node verison >=11.0.0...