# While deploy the MERN Stack at DigitalOcean error TextEncoder is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean, mern

My app works on development but gives Text Encoder error in production. When I run the Node index.js command, I get the error "TextEncoder is not defined".

**Error**

[image: 1]

**Index.js file**

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const posts = require("./routes/posts.js");
const categories = require("./routes/categories.js");
const http = require("http");

dotenv.config();
const server = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(cors());

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("connected mongodb"))
  .catch(() => console.log("connection error"));

server.use("/api/posts", posts);
server.use("/api/categories", categories);

const httpServer = http.createServer(server);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));

  server.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/client" + "/build" + "/index.html"));
  });

  httpServer.listen(80);
} else {
  server.listen(PORT, () => console.log("server listening at", PORT));
}
```

**Package.json**

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: What is node version on server and  your local system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined)

Comment: Server : 10.19.0
Local : 14.17.6

Comment: @iLuvLogix This won't solve the issue. Also he is not using the module as it is, it's a dependency from node_modules

Comment: @vsay Please update your node version on server, it'll work fine

Comment: Thank you @HarshitRastogi. I updated the node version and the problem was solved.

Comment: Glad it helped :)