# const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder(); in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, nodes

I am trying to use mongodb so I install mongoose package

but the problem is when I am writing like this

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //getting error here
```

It showing me error like this

```
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder();
                    ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
```

If I am commenting mongoose line I don't get any error but I need to use this even i checked my node version its 16.5.0
I tried looking an old post where same error occur but its not understandable to me any help ? old post link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined)

how to fix this error

Comment: Check my comment, it's a node version issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open your encoding.js folder in node_modules>whatwg-url>dist

and write this code

```
"use strict";
var util= require('util');
const utf8Encoder = new util.TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new util.TextDecoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });
```

in place of

```
"use strict";
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });
```

all you where missing is this small part by including utils

```
var util= require('util');
const utf8Encoder = new util.TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new util.TextEncoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me at the top of my small script file.

```
"use strict";
const util = require('util');
global.TextEncoder = util.TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = util.TextDecoder;
```

Comment: You can also add it to jest.setup.js is you are encountering it in your tests.

Answer (score 3):

It's a compatibility issue with `node.js` version, upgrade your node.js version and then reinstall node packages.

Upgrade your version with: `v16.14.2`

It's not recommended to modify files inside the `node_modules` folder

You can use NVM to manage multiple node.js versions, here are the installation guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Seems not necessary to go to `v16.14.2`. Just fixed this by going to `v14.21.1`. Version `v14.17.4` works as well, and probably several before that.

Answer (score 1):

Open your encoding.js folder in node_modules

1. Open the node_modules
2. Locate the whawg-url folder and open.
3. Search for dist folder - there, you'd find the encoding.js folder
4. Open via VS Code or any IDE of your choice.

Replace these line of code

```
"use strict";
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });
```

With this --

```
"use strict";
var util= require('util');
const utf8Encoder = new util.TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new util.TextDecoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });
```

Then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

[image: TextEncoder is not defined node error]

This seems to be an issue with older node versions. You need to use the latest node. If you are using `nvm` type

```
nvm use node
```

Note: to download latest node with `nvm` use this command

```
nvm install --lts
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your using an old version of node, if you install node using **apt install node**, you get an old version. So you need to upgrade to a recent version of node.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a compatible node version of libraries in package.json. I encountered the same error the mistake I made is that I used nvm and I ran `npm install` with node `v12.x.x` for some reason nvm did not set the current version it set `v10.x.x` when I returned to the project folder. so here what I resolved the error:

```bash
$ rm -rf node_modules
# use another way to switch to the correct version if not using nvm
$ nvm use v12.x.x # Switch node version to v12.x.x
$ npm install
# then restart the server
```

if you use nvm and you want to set the project node version automatically when entering the project folder, just follow this [instruction](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration).