# ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined after using a previous version of jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

the backend test run successfully at the latest version which is 27.3.1, but because the react script needs it to be 26.6.0, I reinstall it at this version, but the test is now failed to run.

[image]

[image: this is my project structure]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined)

Comment: Pls use images only when necessary instead type code and error in ``` ```