# Deploy NestJS with PM2

Tags: nestjs, pm2

I'm trying to deploy my Angular + NestJS application on my Ubuntu server with PM2 and NGINX.
I have build my server, that listens to port 3003. Here is the content of the **dist** folder :

[image]

I then used PM2 as follows:

```
pm2 start ./main.js --name my-backend
```

If I try to go on my server IP address, on port 3003, e.g. http://99.99.99.99:3003 nothing happen, I get a page that says we can't access the website, with error code **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Do you know what I did wrong ?

**EDIT** Well I did something wrong because I have the following error : TextEncoder is not defined

[image]

Comment: Could you share a list of running apps: `pm2 list` and some logs: `pm2 logs`. More info at: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Comment: @Robert-JanKuyper oh yeah, I forgot to check the logs... I edited the post with the error I get. Seems to be related to mongodb , I'm gonna check that

Comment: Can you provide more details such as the package.json and the code how you connect with Mongo.

Comment: @Robert-JanKuyper I just managed to make it work. I thank you for your help. I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined 

I think I need to upgrade npm and node so that I can have the latest versions of those modules. I started on ubuntu 18.4 that I upgraded to 20.4 but I didn't upgrade the npm and node versions. I think my problem is solved ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that a node module had an error: **mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js** was the problem.
I had to edit the file, then use this solution : [ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined)

I think I need to upgrade my NPM and Node on Ubuntu, so that I can have the latest versions, as I'm running node v10 and can go to v14.