# ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined when importing jsdom library

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I have these two files:

**test.js**:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const hello  = () =>  {
  console.log("hello!");
};


module.exports = {
    hello
};
```

and

**server.js**:

```
const hello = require('./stuff/test');

hello.hello();
```

**directory structure**:

```
myprojectfolder
             backend
                    src
                       stuff
                           test.js
                       server.js
```

When I run `server.js` I get the `ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined` error:

```
/home/myusername/projects/myprojectfolder/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js:2
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder();
                    ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
```

If I remove `const jsdom = require("jsdom");` line from `test.js`, `server.js` runs fine and without any errors (outputs `hello`).

Why does it happen and how do I fix it (while still being able to import and use `jsdom` inside `test.js`?).

Comment: Is this in Node.js and if so which version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Boaz I was using NodeJS version `10`, tried version `16` and it runs fine, thank you!

Comment: Indeed, the `TextEncoder` constructor is only available (globally) from Node 12. This is covered in the duplicate post.

Comment: I'm using nodejs v18 and still get the error.  I even installed text-encoder.  Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it took me all day, but finally I managed to pull it together.
My problem was that tests didn't run because of that error.

So, in package.json under "scripts" I added the following:

```
"test": "jest --verbose --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit"
```

And in jest.config.js, I added the following:

```
   globals: {
      "ts-jest": {
         tsConfigFile: "tsconfig.json"
       },
       TextEncoder: require("util").TextEncoder,
       TextDecoder: require("util").TextDecoder
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain why removing --runInBand causes the test to fail?