# Update node_module manually after app been deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, heroku-api

Everytime I host my current project to heroku it gets crashed saying *ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined at Object. (/app/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js:2:21)* after updating the module as mentioned and wasting almost a whole day , I got to know that heroku installs node_modules independently , so my question how can i change the modules of a deployed app to heroku??

Any help Appreciated

Comment: Changing things in `node_modules/` is an antipattern. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The Textencoder is not defined in the whatwg-url/lib/encoding /.js module so I am getting the error like mentioned in this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined and I want to make changes as said there