# "ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined" while trying to build next.js project on ubuntu server

Tags: reactjs, linux, next.js, server, digital-ocean

I just made a newly setup of an ubuntu server, which I am trying to deploy my next.js project. On the development environment, the command `npm run build` works fine but on the server, when I run `sudo npm run build`, it returns

```
> @ build /var/www/paysure_admin
> next build

info  - Checking validity of types  
error - ESLint: Module.createRequire is not a function
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc.js" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data ./var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
info  - Collecting page data .../var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
info  - Collecting page data ./var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
info  - Collecting page data .../var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
info  - Collecting page data ./var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
info  - Collecting page data .../var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
(node:2921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12037)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12975)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
(node:2921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 361)
(node:2921) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
info  - Collecting page data ./var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
(node:2921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12037)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12975)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
(node:2921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 362)
info  - Collecting page data ./var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9
'use strict';var h=require("react");function n(a,d){a.enqueue(d);return 0<a.desiredSize}var q=new TextEncoder;function r(a,d){"function"===typeof a.error?a.error(d):a.close()}var t=JSON.stringify,u=Symbol.for("react.module.reference"),v=60103,w=60107,x=60112,y=60115,z=60116;if("function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for){var A=Symbol.for;v=A("react.element");w=A("react.fragment");x=A("react.forward_ref");y=A("react.memo");z=A("react.lazy")}var B=Array.isArray,C=h.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;
                                                                                              ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-writer.browser.production.min.server.js:9:95)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/writer.browser.server.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)

> Build error occurred
{ Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12037)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/var/www/paysure_admin/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12975)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12) type: 'WorkerError' }
info  - Collecting page data .npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-01-21T13_58_11_336Z-debug.log
```

I use `sudo npm run build` because I am not the root user of the server.

**Node Version** ===> v16.19.0
**npm version** ===> 8.19.3

##### Package.json File

```
{
  "babelMacros": {
    "twin": {
      "preset": "emotion"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.13.1",
    "@emotion/css": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.66",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.3.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.3.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.36.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "downshift": "^6.1.7",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "generate-unique-id": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "next": "12.0.9",
    "next-connect": "^0.13.0",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.13",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.40.0",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.4.0",
    "react-paystack": "^3.0.5",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.4",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "swr": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "twin.macro": "^2.8.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried downgrading my node to version 14 but still of no use

Comment: Have you checked this question out - [ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

if you directly install node on ubuntu, it installs version-10, you need to configure settings and then install node so as to get the latest version, v18, I'm not sure but this may be the reason, btw try to check the version of node installed on your ubuntu instance.